# Dismiss keyboard on drag with TableView and UITextView doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've a setup as shown in the screenshot below. I've set Keyboard to **Dismiss on drag** in IB for scroll view. It doesn't dismiss keyboard on drag in my project.

However it does work on a dummy test project so it seems there is something in my project which is causing it not to work. I can't figure out what that thing is.

Any help or insights on how to find out the issue and fix?

P.S. It's lot of code so I may not be able to paste all the code here for this VC. If you need any specific section code to see then let me know.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting **Dismiss Interactively** on `UITableView` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set **Dismiss interactively**